# How can I search a specific column in text file for a user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to ask the user for a string that they would like to search for in a specific column. Its the second column in a tab delimited text file, and find and print every instance where it occurs in that column.

I want the user to be able to just enter even a snippet of the item, doesn't matter uppercase or lowercase, and get the full items back. In this case the second column contains a list of authors and I want the user to be able to search for an author and return the name of the author and the name of the book they've written, which is in the same line, but is in the first column.

```
def file_search():
    userInput = input('Enter a string: ')
    lowerInput = userInput.lower()
    f=open('file.txt','r')
    lowerInput=f.readlines()
    result=[]
    for x in lowerInput:
        result.append(x.split(' ')[1])
    f.close()
```

This is what I've tried but my 'list index is out of range'
A line looks like

```
A Widow For One Year    John Irving     Random House    6/14/1998   Fiction
Accident    Danielle Steel  Delacorte   2/27/1994   Fiction
Acheron     Sherrilyn Kenyon    St. Martin's    8/24/2008   Fiction
Advise and Consent      Allen Drury    Doubleday    10/4/1959   Fiction
Against All Enemies    Tom Clancy   Putnam   7/3/2011   Fiction
Airframe    Michael Crichton    Knopf   12/29/1996  Fiction
Airport    Arthur Hailey    Doubleday   4/7/1968    Fiction
```

Comment: I've added a few more lines, they all look like this, book title, author, publisher, date, genre

Comment: Why did you use split by ' '? Because in the name, it also has the ' ' (space?) characters.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Comment: This seems difficult as is. If you have a csv, why not use the csv module?  In any case, unless you split on **tabs**, there is no notion of 2nd column in your data - split by space will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit but it should definitely get you going. If for example you enter "john" you'll find everything about his work.

```
def file_search():
    userInput = input('Enter a string: ').lower()
    result = []
    with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
        for x in f:
            if userInput in x.lower():
                result.append(x.split('   '))

    for s in result:
        print(s[1] + " has written: "+ s[0])

file_search()
```

Comment: How can I modify this so that it's only searching the second column

Comment: I thought you had tabs but they were spaces instead. With it now, you should be able to print both first and second columns

Comment: Ok, I reread your question, fixed it so that it only prints the second column

Comment: This works great except I'm not sure why it is only printing the first result and not all the results

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought you said you only wanted the author name and book? So you want all the columns related to that one author?

Comment: Oh yea, I'm sorry if that was unclear. I wanted to be able to search for an author name and it returns every book and author that fits what was entered. So if I search Rowling I'm gonna get all the books shes written